# add the rules to open a port using iptable, then the hadoop cluster does not working

Tags: hadoop, iptables

I am managing a 4-node hadoop cluster, which has 1 master node and 3 datanode, I am trying to open a port in master node, using the command below, the command is appended  to the /etc/sysconfig/iptables

```
-A INPUT -m state --state New -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1015 -j ACCEPT
```

Then, I save the iptables, and restart the iptables

```
 /etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

Also restart the ipservice like below, then the data node can not communicate with master node anymore, even I try to revoke what I have done, would be appreciate if anyone can suggest so that I can re-use the Hadoop cluster since I have important data on it.

```
service iptables restart
```

Comment: Why not disable firewall for datanode running machines?

Comment: You could run `service iptables stop` to disable the firewall, but i'd also make sure you restart your cluster after to ensure everything is connected

Answer (score 1):

Most clusters i've ever worked with tend to be firewall less between the various hadoop nodes but operate on separate network with a gateway node between the normal network and the hadoop cluster (and it's this gateway node that has the firewall to control access to the cluster as a whole).

If you do want to pursue running a firewall on the namenode, there are a couple of links i found with a google search "Hadoop iptables" that list a more complete set of iptable rules that your 1 liner.

Obviously you'll need to amend for your IP network address space and hadoop port numbers, but they are a good starting point:

Search on each page for "iptables":

- https://www.triumf.info/wiki/DAQwiki/index.php/HADOOP
- https://sites.google.com/a/lyz.jp/distributed-computing-research/subprojects/hadoop/00600
- https://www.google.com/search?q=hadoop+iptables&oq=hadoop+iptables